# On graded Artinian Gorenstein algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, graded-rings, gorenstein

Let $k$ be a field and $R$ an $\mathbb{N}$-graded $k$-algebra that is graded-commutative. Assume that $\dim_k R<\infty$ and that $R$ is Gorenstein (i.e. the injective dimension of $R$ over itself is finite). Then why are the following product maps non-degenerate?

> $$R_i\times R_{n-i}\rightarrow R_n$$

where $R_n$ is the last non-zero degree of $R$.

EDIT: The proof on the fourth page of [this paper](http://www.dmi.unict.it/~frusso/DMI/Seminari_2015_files/Maeno_Watanabe.pdf) works for standard graded rings (i.e. rings generated in degree 1). Is the claim still true for rings not generated in degree 1? And do we need $R_n$ to be one-dimensional?

Comment: Do you know in your situation, injective dimension of $R$ is in fact zero and thus $R$ is self-injective? Do you know that $R$  is also the injective hull of $k=R/m$, where $m=R_1+\cdots$? These will show that $R$ is isomorphic as $R$-modules to $\operatorname{Hom}_k(R,k)$ and then easy to prove the non-degeneracy.

Comment: I see that $R$ is self-injective. How do I see that $R$ is the injective hull of $k$? I was trying to prove that $R$ is an essential extension of $k$ but is seems to me that what that means is that every non-zero ideal of $R$ contains an element of $k$, maybe I'm misunderstanding something. How do I prove that $R$ is iso to $Hom_k(R,k)$ as $R$-modules? I was looking at the injection $k\rightarrow R$, dualizing it we get an injection $Hom_k(R,k)\rightarrow Hom_k(k,k)\cong k$, so it seems to me that $Hom_k(R,k)\cong k$, in particular is one-dimensional, where is my mistake?

Answer (score 2):

All these can be found in the excellent classic `On ubiquity of Gorenstein rings' by Hyman Bass. So, let $R$ be a self injective local ring of finite length with $k$ the residue field. Then the functor $N\mapsto N^*=\operatorname{Hom}_R(N,R)$ is exact. This immediately implies $\ell(N^*)=e\ell(N)$ for all finite length modules where $\ell$ stands for length and $e=\ell(k^*)$. But, $R^*=R$ implies $e=1$. Now, I hope that it is clear $R$ is the injective hull of $k$.